# SQL outer join

Tags: sql

I've got 3 tables. The SQL below should explain a little of the data in there that I need:

```
SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.DOB, m.Gender, a.Address1, a.Address2, a.City, 
a.State, a.Country, a.PostCode from Members m 
LEFT JOIN Addresses a ON m.Id = a.MemberId 
INNER JOIN AddressType at ON at.Id = a.AddressTypeId 
WHERE m.Email = 'member2@test.com' AND at.Type = 'Account'
```

If data is present in the Members for the user but not in the addresses I still need the FirstName, LastName etc to be returned but the Address etc as NULL. Currently it's all coming back as null. I thought I could do this with an outer join but I've tried and can't get it to pull what I need back. Am I thinking completely wrong or just doing it wrong? And yes, if I'm doing it wrong I'd love it if you could tell me what and how. :)

EDIT:

I made the modification suggested but:

```
SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.DOB, m.Gender, a.Address1, a.Address2, a.City, 
a.State, a.Country, a.PostCode from Members m 
LEFT JOIN Addresses a ON m.Id = a.MemberId 
LEFT JOIN AddressType at ON at.Id = a.AddressTypeId 
WHERE m.Email = 'member2@test.com' AND at.Type = 'Account'
```

this doesn't work. When I remove the AddressType:

```
SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.DOB, m.Gender, a.Address1, a.Address2, a.City, 
a.State, a.Country, a.PostCode from Members m 
LEFT JOIN Addresses a ON m.Id = a.MemberId 
WHERE m.Email = 'member2@test.com'
```

it pulls back the data so I know the first join is working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` on both joins. Right now the first join acts as you want it to, but the following `INNER JOIN` tries to match the `at.Id = a.AddressTypeId` condition on a `NULL` and it can't, so the row isn't returned.

An `INNER JOIN` will return a non-empty, non-`NULL` result only if it can satisfy its `ON` condition.

Comment: Hi Vache, Still not quite working. I've done some edits to show what worked and what didn't.

Comment: It's because of your `AND at.Type = 'Account'` condition that isn't true when there is no address. Try `AND (at.Type = 'Account' OR at.Type IS NULL)`. Sorry, I should have seen it at first.

Comment: "An INNER JOIN requires fields to exist in both tables to return a result" -- all SQL tables must have at least one column, therefore the requirement "fields to exist in both tables" is always satisfied! I rather think you had something more specific in mind regarding matching values rather than the existence of columns. Also bear in mind that the empty set is still a result ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `INNER JOIN` on `AddressType` to a `LEFT JOIN` as well, at the moment I think the `INNER JOIN` will be enforcing that fields exist in both tables

Comment: Thanks for the help but that didn't work. I've added some edits to my question to show what I tried.